# How to integrate a custom authorization service with Spring Authorization Server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to customize the Spring Authorization Server to work with my own user management service and authorization service.
I have managed to integrate my authentication service by implementing an `AuthenticationProvider`. I'm using the authorization code flow and when I do an authorize request, It lands me on the form login page. After entering the username and password, it successfully authenticates with my service and returns the response.
So in the response, I have user's groups and other attributes. What I want to do is after authentication, get the users groups from the user management service's response and send those groups and the scopes requested in the authorize call to my authorization service and get the allowed scopes for the user. Then I want to get the user's consent for these scopes and generate the access token with the scopes that the user gives consent to.

My authorize call:
`http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid%20profile%20view_salary%20view_employee&code_challenge=Whubzdv9zyTyeqdpEpouWE1QVQ0tGlMpbn3eJpTuHog&redirect_uri=http://auth-server:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc&code_challenge_method=S256`

Response from the user management service

```
{
    "groups": [
        "manager"
    ],
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "first_name": "John",
    "username": "jdoe"
}
```

Request to be sent to the authorization service

```
{
  "groups": [
    "manager"
  ],
  "requestedScopes": [
    "view_employee",
    "view_salary"
  ]
}
```

Let's assume that the `manager` group only has `view_employee` permission. So my consent screen should prompt these: `view_employee`, `profile`.

After getting the access token, it should have `view_employee`, `profile` as scopes.

Appreciate if you can point me to get this to work. If I understood this incorrectly, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use the OAuth2TokenCustomizer to assert the authorized scopes in to the access token

```
@Bean
    OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
       
        return context -> {
            // Only do this to the access token
            if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
             // Get groups from the authentication response
             List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();

             // In this case, CustomUser extends User which includes groups
             if (user instanceof CustomUser customUser) {
                 groups = customUser.getGroups();
             }
            
             // Get the scopes from the Authorize call
             Set<String> authorizedScopes = context.getAuthorizedScopes();

             // ....perform the API call to my authz service and get allowed scopes

             //Extract the allowedScopes separated by a space
                 String allowedScopesString = authorizedUser.getAllowedScopes().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
             // Replace the "scope" claim in the token
                 context.getClaims().claim("scope", allowedScopesString);
           }
        };
    }
```